# % literal removes first 2 character of string/integer

Tags: php, mysql, string, cakephp, sql-like

I'm trying to build an array to retrieve data from my database using cakephp according to a search value. but I've found an strange behavior. The % literal removes the first two character of any string/integer if its a number.

I'm trying to search everything like %250% then cake or php outputs 0%. it removes the % and 25. This doesn't happen if the $filter is not a number.

This is my code.

```
if(in_array('part', $s)){
    array_push($conditions, array("PN_CLEAN" => $aux));
    array_push($conditions['OR'], array("PN_CLEAN LIKE" => '%'.trim($filter).'%'));
}
if(in_array('brand', $s)){
    array_push($conditions['OR'], array("BRAND_FOR_INVENTORY LIKE" => '%'.trim($filter).'%'));
}
if(in_array('desc', $s)){
    array_push($conditions['OR'], array("DESCRIPTION_FOR_INVENTORY LIKE" => '%'.trim($filter).'%'));
}
if(in_array('cat', $s)){
    array_push($conditions['OR'], array("CATEGORY_FOR_INVENTORY LIKE" => '%'.trim($filter).'%'));
}
```

I've tried casting, sprintf, strval and nothing works.

Thanks

Comment: what happens when you `echo (trim($filter))`?

Comment: I tried to replicate the issue, but seems like it's working fine on my end? The only thing I can think of, is URL decoding. This allows me from going from '%250%' to '%0%'... But it's still not exactly what you're getting, neither it's close to the question.

Comment: Well, actually this is an ajax request using jquery datatables plugin + cakephp 1.3. If i echo '%'.$filter or "%$filter" it echoes %0%. but if I add an space or a literal like '% '.$filter or '%-'.$filter or "%-$fiter" nothing happens. I mean the result is "% 250" or "%-250"

Comment: I've found, but I've not found what's going on. When I call a function to get some results the problem raises...